# SSH not working through Linux bridge

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ssh, bridge

I am currently struggling with a very strange problem. I have a Linux Ubuntu 16.04 machine with two interfaces (`eth1` and `eth2`). I set up a bridge between these two interfaces with `bridge-utils` for the following simple setup:

*laptop1 → bridge → laptop2*

where the *bridge* is the Ubuntu computer with the stated interfaces.

On *laptop2* there is an `openssh` server running. When I now try to `ssh` from *laptop1* to *laptop2* it is not working. The bridge itself works, cause pinging and stuff works.

I also used `wireshark` to examine the problem. The SSH handshake just works fine but after some packets the transmission gets stuck in a TCP retransmission flow until it times out or terminates. I spent a few hours on online research but nobody seems to have this problem.

The only hint I found was disabling the LRO feature. But that did not solve my problem. Maybe I am missing something else.

Maybe someone has a hint or clue to solve my problem.

Comment: decrease the mtu

Comment: I came here to write what @IporSircer said 6 seconds earlier - it may be that the 1 laptop is using jumbo frames (bigger then 1500 bytes).  MTU issues can cause the types of problem described.

Comment: I checked the laptop settings. The interface uses mtu = 1500. And no jumbo frames. What i don't understand is why the bridge should not work with the interfaces set to mtu 1500 as well.

Comment: Are  you using ethernet-to-USB adapters, by chance?

Comment: Yes indeed. I use usb ethernet adapters. Is there a problem with USB Adapters?

Answer (score -1):

umm 
I have the same issue on a raspberry pi 3

Taking off eth0 from br0 i.e. brctl delif br0 eth0
brings back connectivity but obviously stops bridge from workin

used to work a few months ago

D

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than a solution.